# How do I make the 'man' utility as comprehensive as ss64.com?

Tags: linux, man

The 'man' utility that comes with a Debian distro is not as comprehensive as ss64.com, and in environment like cygwin, it is even more so. Is there a software or a script that will make my 'man' more like ss64 pages? ss64.com contains command line reference for many different environments including Windows CMD and Mac OS X, and bash. One example I have is the man page for [read](http://ss64.com/bash/read.html)

**Edit:**
From [lifehacker.com](http://lifehacker.com/5778769/make-the-man-command-more-useful-in-linux-and-os-x), I found the following function:

```
man () { /usr/bin/man $@ || (help $@ 2> /dev/null && help $@ | less) }
```

help utility gives me the page I am looking for - but it does not bypass the underwhelming man page for `read`.

Comment: Could you please include some information on what ss64.com is?

Comment: If you are connected to the 'Net, a bit of scripting with `lynx` or `w3m` will give you access to ss64.com and whatever other site you use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a man page for `read` (in section 1 of the manual) that says anything else than *"There is no `read` command, but your shell might have a `read` builtin command, see your shell manual for details"* is misleading, because `read` is a shell builtin and the behaviour and supported options vary from shell to shell.

Some systems (generally not Linux ones) however do have a `read` command (in `/bin`, `/usr/bin` or elsewhere) as POSIX requires (but the Linux Standard Base (LSB) specification lifts that requirement), and on those systems, the man page will describe the behaviour of *that* `read` command, and will be misleading because it's generally not *that* `read` that you invoke when you call `read` at a shell prompt or in a shell script or in `system()`, `popen()`... but the shell builtin one.

That http://ss64.com site describes the `bash` builtin `read` command (though it doesn't say which version of `bash`, and for instance, it's different from the `read` builtin in the version of `bash` on this machine, which itself is different from that `read` from the `bash` of another (older) machine I have access to) in a `bash` section. In that regard, it's not misleading, but where it's very misleading is where it puts all sorts of *other* non-bash related commands in that [same section](http://ss64.com/bash/) and sort of implies that `bash` (one of many shells available on Linux and other Unices, shells being one of many ways to run commands) is necessary to run those commands or that those commands have anything to do with it.

Now, when you do `man read`, if there's no `read` command in section 1 (user commands) of the manual, it will search in other sections. For instance, if you have installed the `manpages-dev` package (on Debian), you'll get the man page of the `read` system call (in section 2). If not, but you have installed the TCL documentation package, you'll get the man page for the `read` TCL function in section `3tcl`.

You can ask explicitly for the `read` user command with `man 1 read` (`man -s 1 read` on some systems). If your manual had a `1bash` section, it would bring it up before the one in section `1zsh`, so you'd need to write it `man 1zsh read` to get the `zsh` variant. You can get all the man pages with `man -a read`, you can find out what packages they come from on Debian with: `dpkg -S $(man -wa read)`. For instance, on this system, I have:

```
$ dpkg -S $(man -wa read)
9base: /usr/share/man/man1/plan9-read.1.gz
tcl8.5-doc: /usr/share/man/man3/read.3tcl.gz
manpages-dev: /usr/share/man/man2/read.2.gz
```

With `zsh`, pressing <kbd>Alt-H</kbd> at the prompt brings the manual (via the `man` command) for the command you're currently typing. The default `zsh` installation on Debian improves it to make use of the `run-help` function (see `info -f zsh --index-search=run-help`), so you get help for the builtins as well.

With the `fish` shell, there's a `help` builtin function that tries to bring the most sensible documentation for a given command or `fish` concept (from `man` or the `fish` documentation).

If for some reason, you're forced to using `bash` (grin) or can't be bothered to change from the default, `bash` also has a `help` builtin command that brings help on `bash` builtins (however note that `help read` is like `help '*read*'`, that is it brings the manual for all the builtins whose name contains `read`, use `help '[r]ead'` for instance, if you only want the `read` manual).

`bash`'s help only works for `bash` builtins. If you want to extend it to include search in the manual in sections 1 (user commands) and 6 (games) and 8 (administrative commands), you could redefine it as:

```
help() {
  builtin help "$@" 2> /dev/null ||
    MANSECT=1:8:6 man "$@"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

'Hello, author of SS64 here, I stumbled across this question 5 years later. There are some good points in the other answers above and I have re-worded the index page and many of the individual pages to make it clearer which are built-in bash commands and which are general utilities.

Also I would agree with others that no online reference can ever be a replacement for the built in man pages. It is useful to be able to search online and find the commands you need to use, but it is always wise to check they do match the syntax of your own machine.

To answer the question, probably the best and most permanent way to improve your local man pages is to contribute to the [Linux Documentation project](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/contributing.html)

I have long felt that Linux could do with 'out of the box' HTML man pages and ubuntu are doing [some work](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/) on that.

Comment: How does this answer the actual question, which is "***Is there a software or a script that will make my 'man' more like ss64 pages?***"?

Answer (score 2):

As Stephane hints a potential pitfall of favouring online man pages is that they document older or newer versions of software than what you have.  For this reason alone I think it is a very bad practice to start *replacing* them with ones you prefer, because at some future point there may be some subtlety concerning versions which is important -- and that could be greatly complicated if you have replaced the official docs with informative but inadvertently *incorrect* docs.

I have not used ss64.com, but it does look like a decent reference for certain things; I presume it is actually intended to target **cygwin** users as the "bash" category is really a mash-up of bash built-ins and common unix commands. Since the later technically have *nothing to do with bash*, this makes the site's content potentially misleading, but it would make sense from a cygwin perspective.

I do agree the GNU man pages on linux (I think those ship with cygwin too) are sometimes not as good as others -- eg, the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) pages are generally more in depth than the stuff in section 3, and since linux conforms to posix, I take them as valid.  But I still would not replace my system pages with them -- what's the point?

All these things are effectively complementary; your system pages are what they are.  Nowadays most people have a continuous high speed internet connection, and the amount of time it takes to actually *read* a piece of documentation completely dwarfs the time it takes to access over a network.  However, I do sometimes mirror sites I find so useful that having them right at hand would be nice:

```
wget -r -np -k -p http://www.site.com/dir/page.html
```

The address is the top level index of the documentation, so eg. "ss64.com/bash/" would probably work.  The switches are in described in `man wget`.  So you download the site to a local directory, bookmark it in your browser or create an index of such, and done.