# Why is the manual for 'where' command not available

Tags: man, tcsh, shell-builtin

I recently came across the command `where`, which provides the actual path of executables in Linux. I was aware of `which`, `whereis`, `locate` and  `find`, but not `where`.

I want to know when this command got introduced and why its manual is not available. Is this shell command specific to the C Shell or do all shells have the `where` command?

Comment: If, in bash, you want to find out if a command is built-in or external (or a function, or an alias, ...), `type where` is your friend.

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167004/ .

Answer (score 6):

The only shells I know which has a builtin command called `where` is the `tcsh` and `zsh`. In the manual page of that shell (`man tcsh` / `man zshbuiltins`), you can find the definition:

```
   where command (+)
           Reports all known instances of command, including aliases, builtins and
           executables in path.
```

Therefore it is the `tcsh`-equivalent of the `bash` builtin `type` (`tcsh` has no `type`):

```
tcsh$ where where
where is a shell built-in
tcsh$ where echo
echo is a shell built-in
/bin/echo
```

Answer (score 5):

where is a shell builtin command in csh

```
    where where
    where is a shell built-in
```

the builtin is also available in zsh.

Answer (score 2):

The linux command is called `which`. If you are used to in c-shells this might be a builtin. Bash builtins are documented through the bash builtin `help`.

From Wikipedia:tcsh

> The built-in where command. Works like the which command but shows all locations of the target command in the directories specified in $PATH rather than only the one that will be used.

So I'm right: The where command is a tcsh built-in and not available as an external command. If you pay me 250$ I will write a little C command for you ;)

Comment: No, the Linux command is `type` in Bourne-style shells (including bash, which is usually the default interactive shell on Linux) and `which` on csh. `which` also exists as an external command, but [should not be used outside (t)csh since it's unreliable](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then).