# How do I know if the man page I'm looking at is the correct one?

Tags: man

For example,

```
[fakename]$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
```

But `man echo` gives me the GNU coreutils version of `echo`. What's the easiest way to tell if the man page I'm looking at is the correct one, i.e the one for the utility I'd get if I directly invoked it?

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167004/ .

Comment: Adjacently related: [Stack Overflow: What does the number in parentheses shown after Unix command names in manpages mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62936/4561887)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't, really. Not without knowledge external to the man page.

In the case of `echo` (and `printf`, and `test`, ...), it's often a shell builtin, so you'll need to know that and read the shell's documentation.
<sub>(And `echo` is notoriously different in different implementations, [use `printf` instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/170373).)</sub>

In most, if not all shells, you can find if something is a builtin with  `type command`, e.g. `type echo` will print `echo is a shell builtin`. ([`type` is specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/type.html) but e.g. [fish](https://fishshell.com/) supports it too, as non-POSIXy as it is.) In Bash, you'd then read `man bash`, [the online documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-echo), or use [the builtin command `help`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-help) (which is specific to Bash, and which you need to know exists).

Even if the command is *not* a builtin, it's possible that there are several commands with the same name, `rename` being a famous example (see [Why is the rename utility on Debian/Ubuntu different than the one on other distributions, like CentOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275254/170373)). Now, your OS should have the correct man page for the actually installed utility, and e.g. in Debian, [the "alternatives" system](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) updates the corresponding man pages also when the command alternatives are changed. But if you read [an online man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rename), you'll need to be aware of it.

Many utilities have a command line option like `--version` which might tell you what implementation that command is. (But not nearly all utilities have it. I think it's a GNUism originally, so GNU utilities have it, as well as those that happened to copy the custom.) In the case of `rename`, it happens to work in telling two different implementations apart:

```
debian$ rename --version
/usr/bin/rename using File::Rename version 0.20
centos$ rename --version
rename (util-linux-ng 2.17.2)
```

Besides that, your system might have an alias or a function with the same name of a utility, usually to modify the behaviour of the utility. In that case, the defaults presented in a man page might not apply. Aliases for `ls` are common, as are aliases adding `-i` to `rm` or `mv`. But `type foo` would also tell you if `foo` is an alias or function.

Comment: The shell built-in commands doesn't support the `--version` option.

Comment: @GAD3R, yeah, and neither do the standard utilities on BSDs, or many other tools. For shell builtins, it's of course not necessary, since it's the shell's version that applies, so just go check `$BASH_VERSION` in case of Bash... And for other utilities, you need to know if they support that option, which you'd find from the man page, leading us back to the original question. :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want the manual for a built-in command, then you need to look at the manual of your shell.  The command will be documented therein, along with all other built-in commands (or there will at least be a reference to where the documentation for builtins is to be found).

- `bash`: `man bash` or `help echo` from an interactive `bash` shell.
- `zsh`: `man zsh` (and after a bit of reading, `man zshbuiltin`)
- `fish`: `man fish` (and after a bit of reading, `help echo`)

The manual that you get for `man echo` documents `/bin/echo`, i.e. the *external* `echo` command.  This command is not what you would use when you use `echo` without an explicit path.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, on a user friendly UNIX, you get the documentation for all `test` versions if you type `man test`.

Comment: @schily I'd rather run my unfriendly Unix where I get specific info about exactly what I ask for :-)

Comment: You do not seem to like useful answers :-( If you did have a look at the sample man page, you did write a more useful answer,

Comment: @schily An answer does not become more useful by referring to manual that are not available on the target system.  A Unix does not become "friendly" by documenting every conceivable version of every external utility. It becomes confusing.

Comment: An answer cannot be called useful if it confuses the reader and the Linux man page for `echo` is not helpful as it informs about builtin `echo` versions at a location that most readers don't read.

Comment: @schily The OP knows that the `echo` command is a built-in and asks where to get the correct information about built-in commands. The correct answer is to look at the shell's manual. In what way is this not useful?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to invoke the non-shell-internal version by giving the full path (which you could get with `which echo`). There are not separate manpages for shell internals; for documentation on those you'll want to look for the manpage for your shell. The "type" command you mention above is the best way to figure out which you'll get.

Comment: My question was how to tell whether the man page is correct. Perhaps the example was misleading; I am speaking more so of two commands that have the same name (different versions of ps or something), and how to tell whether the info I’m getting from the man page is accurate.

Comment: Your phrasing indicates some confusion ; the man page is correct for the independent binaries on your system, but whether you're running the binaries or the shell internal version of these commands depends on what you do and what configuration options you have. The most common source of surprise here is shell-internal versus external binary. That said, it is possible (if unlikely) you might have multiple versions of the same command present on your system. If that's the case, you can see if you have the right manpage by asking your package manager to list all files in the package for a util.

Answer (score -1):

Since the command you want to get information on is a shell built-in, typing `help <command name>` in the same shell will give you the correct help entry:

```
$ help echo
echo: echo [-neE] [arg ...]
    Write arguments to the standard output.
    ...
```

Alternatively, you can type `man bash`(or whatever shell you are using) and find the builtin you were looking for.

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to verify that a man page fully matches the command you want to run. Getting the "right" page is trickier than it seems, as that will depend on many factors such as the command's full path, environment variables and aliases, and it's technically impossible for `man` do account for all such factors. However, after a short while you should develop general understanding of where to look for help.

If I were to describe a general algorithm of getting the right documentation on most modern *nices, it would look something like this:

- Do you need help with a built-in (`type <command>` says it's built-in)?

  - Use `help <command>` or `man <shellname>` if `help` is unavailable in your shell.
- Do you want your help succinct and technical?

  - Use `man <command>` (or `man <section> <command>` if there are multiple entries in different sections, see `man man` for the list of sections)
- Do you want your help in the form of a lengthier interactive tutorial/manual (if available)?

  - use `info <command>`
- If the above steps fail:

  - Check `/usr/share/doc/<package name>` for additional documentation on the package, such as HTML pages.
  - Run the command with the `-h` or `--help` options, assuming the command is to be trusted. That will oftentimes give a brief summary of what it does and tell you where you can find more information.
  - Google.

but I must reiterate, this all will become "natural" as one spends some time with the OS.

Comment: Only if the current shell happens to be `bash`.

Comment: Correct, on a typical UNIX, you get `ERROR: Key 'echo' not found (he1)` since `help` is a command from the SCCS suite.

Comment: @Kusalananda based on OP's tag history I highly suspect the shell in question is bash, but fair enough! I would encourage using `help` if it's available, however, since it is the most straightforward way of getting help with any builtins your shell has.

Comment: On OpenBSD, which does not use `bash` by default, `help` is a synonym for `man`, which would give the wrong version of the manual when used as `help echo`.

Answer (score -4):

`man` is split in section:

1. General Section
2. System Calls
3. Library Functions
4. File Formats
5. Games and screensavers
6. Miscellaneous
7. System administration

Depending on what you are looking for you can invoke `man` like that to avoid confusion: `man section command`.

For more information you can actually use `man man`

Answer (score -4):

If your OS distro does not have man pages for those programs that mention the differences, you should make bug report.

In fact, this is the task of the distro creators, but if you type:

```
type cmdname
```

you will get output whether `cmdname` is a shell builtin. If you know what shell you are using, you could run:

```
man shellname
```

replacing `shellname` with the name ouf your shell. The man page of your shell should contain information about builtin commands.

Let me give an example on how a user friendly UNIX should document this: http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/test.1.html

Comment: You're answering a different question; namely, this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62936/4561887