# Bash wait for all subprocesses of script

Tags: bash, background-process

I have a script with

```
for i in 1 2 3 4; do
    do_something $i &
done
```

And when I call it, it terminates before all `do_something` terminated. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0) with many different answers.

*Edit*: `help wait` tells me that

> If ID is not given, waits for all currently active child processes, and the return    status is zero.

Is it not sufficient to just add a single `wait` at the end?

Comment: No you need to wait for each of the process to complete. There is an answer suggesting how to wait for all the bg processes in your link

Comment: What is your question? `wait` is a shell builtin. [Use `help wait` instead of `man wait`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167004/why-dont-shell-builtins-have-proper-man-pages)

Comment: @pLumo See edit

Comment: Why don't you just try? E.g. `for i in 1 2 3 4; do sleep $i & done; wait`. Spoiler: Yes it is sufficient.

Comment: @pLumo Because it's critical that it work for the real world use case and I would rather rely on knowledge than a single example :)

Comment: anyways, you might want to use `parallel do_something ::: 1 2 3 4;`

Comment: Notice that wait only works with _direct_ children of your script. If you use `(do_something $i &)` (ie in a subshell) your `wait` will not wait for it, because the actual `do_something` process will be reparented to pid 1 (init).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it's enough to use a single `wait` with no arguments at the end to wait for all background jobs to terminate.

Note that background jobs started in a subshell would need to be waited for in the same subshell that they were started in. You have no instance of this in the code that you show.

Note also that the [question that you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100) asks about *checking the exit status* of the background jobs.  This *would* require `wait` to be run once for each background job (with the PID of that job as an argument).

Comment: This did not work for me. A single line of `wait` at the end with no parameters, did not help me. I loop over git repositories and pull them. Coming from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/687979/how-to-know-all-subshells-are-executed-and-finished) question.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati That question and the question linked to in the question above both start background jobs in a subshell but call `wait` outside that subshell.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, even though a single wait without parameters should be sufficient, this is not a good practice (relay on a default behaviour). I would collect the pid returned from each call, and wait for these pids explicitly.

Comment: Why would relying on default behaviour be bad practice? The `wait` command is [a standard command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/wait.html) with well defined semantics.

Comment: This answer would be seriously improved if it included any reasons for `wait` without arguments being not a good practice.