# umask does not have -S option

Tags: rhel, csh, umask

I'm trying to use `umask -S` to show the current mask in symbolic form (per `man umask` on my system, which gives me the page BASH_BUILTINS(1)). But `umask` doesn't seem to behave as the manpage claims:

```
user$ umask
22
user$ umask -S
umask: Improper mask.
user$ umask -p
umask: Improper mask.
user$ which umask
umask: shell built-in command.
```

I'm running this in `csh` on RHEL 6.9. Something like `umask 022` works fine. Why would the behavior differ from the manpage?

Comment: Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167004/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/460567/ , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68876/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `umask` changes the internal state of the shell, it has to be a shell builtin.

POSIX shells `umask` builtin have a `-S` option as that's a POSIX requirement, but `csh`'s doesn't. Your `umask` man page documents the `umask` builtin of `bash`, not that of `csh`. Check the csh man page for the documentation of *its* `umask` builtin.

There's no good reason why you'd want to use `csh` in this century, especially on a GNU/Linux system, but if you have to, you can always do:

```
sh -c 'umask -S'
```

to report a symbolic form of that `umask`.

That would report the `umask` of the the child process executing `sh`, but since the `umask` is inherited upon fork and preserved across exec, that should be the same as `csh`'s `umask`.

In any case, that returned `umask` won't be useful to `csh`, as `csh`'s `umask` builtin doesn't support symbolic forms.

Comment: "There's no good reason why you'd want to use [x] in this century [...]" Hm I don't have a good reason. Maybe only a mediocre one: "Because that's what this system administrator has decided to use, and I'm not that administrator." ;) Being new to `csh` I'm surprised `man [builtin]` would not give me info on the builtin *in the context of my current shell*, but that's not relevant to the question. Thanks for the clarification. I can see `man csh` does not give any options, as you say.

Comment: `man` is not a builtin command of `csh` (or any shell for that matters). There's only one `man` command, so it can only give you *one* man page for a given word. Some systems may have different sections for the documentation of different shell builtins, I don't know of any though. Try `man -a umask` on your system to see if any other man page for `umask` comes up and note the section they're in (note that many languages, beside shells have a `umask` function)